# Class diagram from ecore

Tags: eclipse, emf, model-driven, model-driven-development

I have .ecore metamodel. How can I automatically generate class diagram from it?

Answer (score 0):

[EcoreTools2](https://www.eclipse.org/ecoretools/) is the standard diagram editor for Ecore models in Eclipse. They have a [documentation article](https://www.eclipse.org/ecoretools/doc/index.html#CreatingdiagramsfromanexistingEcore) explaining how to create a diagram from an existing Ecore file.

Comment: Thank you. if I have multiple package or I have two .ecore file which links together, How can I have those in one diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Create a EMF project using your .ecore, then when you open the project, there will be a .aird , click right on it , and click on `initialize class diagram ..`